# Remove the key value pairs based on value

Tags: python

```
a:{
   b:{cd:"abc",
      de:"rty"
     },
   c:{cd:"abc",
      de:"uuy"
     },
   d:{cd:"ap",
      de:"uy"
     }
  }
```

I want to print values of cd and de from this dictionary and if the value of cd is same then I only want to print once.
Expected output: b  abc  rty
d  ap   uy

How can I check if the value of cd is repeated or not ?

Edit :

```
 hash_set=set()
 hash_item=v1.get('query_hash',{}).get('sha256', "")
 if hash_item in hash_set:
 break
 else:
 hash_set.add(hash_item)
```

This is not working

Comment: Your formating for a dict is fundamentally messed up. Does it work if you correct it? Also, what does the 'django' tag add to this specific question?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sure @Prune :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if the value of cd is repeated or not ?

If you are iterating over stuff and you don't want to process duplicates keep a container of things you have already seen and skip items if they have been seen. `sets` are excellent containers for membership testing as the *look-up* is O(1) and sets don't *allow* duplicates.

Here is a toy example.

```
stuff = 'anjdusttnnssajd'
seen = set()
for thing in stuff:
    if thing in seen:
        continue
    print(thing.upper())    # process thing
    seen.add(thing)
```

---

Or you could just make a set of the things to process then process the things in the set.

```
stuff = set(stuff)
for thing in stuff:
    print(thing.upper())
```

---

Using your criteria.

```
d = {'a':{'b':{'cd':"abc",'de':"rty"},
          'c':{'cd':"abc",'de':"uuy"},
          'd':{'cd':"ap",'de':"uy"}}}

seen = set()
for key,thing in d['a'].items():
    cd,de = thing['cd'],thing['de']
    if cd in seen:
        continue
    else:
        print(key, cd, de)
        seen.add(cd)
```

Comment: tried that not working. Can you lease see the code in the edit part?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code should help, I formated your JSON a little bit for it to be a valid python string but you should be able to modify it as you wish

```
def getKeys(dict):     
  return [*dict] 

a = {
   'b':{'cd':"abc",
      'de':"rty"
     },
   'c':{'cd':"abc",
      'de':"uuy"
     },
   'd':{'cd':"ap",
      'de':"uy"
     }
  }
cd_list = []
keys = getKeys(a)

for key in keys:
  found = False
  for checked in cd_list:
    if a[key]['cd']==checked:
      found = True
      break
  if not found:
    print( f'{key} : {a[key]["cd"]} {a[key]["de"]}')
    cd_list.append(a[key]['cd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  dict={'a':{
  'b':{'cd':"abc",
  'de':"rty"
    },
  'c':{'cd':"abc",
   'de':"uuy"
   },
  'd':{'cd':"ap",
  'de':"uy"
 }
 }}
 count=0
 for key,item in dict.items():
   for key,i in item.items():
     if item['b']['cd']==i['cd']:
        count=count+1
        lis=i['cd']
   else:
        print(i['cd'])  
if(count>1):
   print(lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your code

```
data = {"a":{"b":{"cd":"abc","de":"rty"},"c":{"cd":"abc","de":"uuy"},"d":{"cd":"ap","de":"uy"}}}
output = set()
for key,val in data.items():
    for key1,val1  in val.items():

        for key2, val2 in val1.items():
            if val2 not in output:
                output.add(key1)
                output.add(val2)


            else:
                break
print(output)
```